# Failed to use CoCreateInstanceFromApp for sensor api, error: -2147221164, GetLastError 1008

Tags: c++, com, windowsiot

Our team need to develop an app runing at IoT Non-UWP environment, and we need to call the sensor COM interface. but it failed at first to use the CoCreateInstanceFromApp/CoCreateInstanceEx.

The code snippet is like this:

```
ULONG ulCount = 0;
COINIT dwCoinit = COINIT_MULTITHREADED;
auto hr2 = CoInitializeEx(NULL, dwCoinit);

if (FAILED(hr2))
  {
  cout << "Failed to run  CoInitializeEx: " << hr2 << endl;
  return;
  }

MULTI_QI res = { 0 };
res.pItf = NULL;
res.hr = S_OK;
res.pIID = &IID_PPV_ARGS(&_pSensor);
//_hr = CoCreateInstanceEx(CLSID_SensorManager,
_hr = CoCreateInstanceFromApp(CLSID_SensorManager,
    NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, 1, &res);
if (S_OK != _hr)
{
   auto result = GetLastError();
   cout << "Failed Create Instance : " << _hr << " WinAPI Error: " << result  <<endl;
   return;
}
```

and it failed with the log:

Failed Create Instance : -2147221164 WinAPI Error: 1008

the error code means:

(-2147221164) “Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))”

1008 means: ERROR_NO_TOKEN

it seems the sensorManager is not available.

Anyone know the method to fix it, and does MSFT expose the sensor api for Non-UWP environment?

Thanks

Jerome

Comment: GetLastError() is not a very good random number generator in this code, do not use it.  CoCreateInstanceFromApp() must only ever be used in an appcontainer, the kind of runtime environment that is provided by a UWP (aka WinRT, aka Store) app.  So never use it in a "non-UWP" app.  IoT is by itself a red flag, runs on midget hardware with a stripped version of Windows.  Which makes it likely that the sensor api is simply not available.  Talk to whomever created the bootable image.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant , I also test with CoCreateInstanceEx which supposed to be valid on non-UWP app. And it failed with them same error code. I think this issue comes from the sensor API. But as MSDN said , the UWP COM api use a subset of the Win32 and COM APIs, while the UWP already support many sensors api in it, i think the IoT non-uwp should have some clue to the sensors api. I also installed the drivers and sure that the sensor can be find via UWP method. Thanks